# Redirecting search page?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this page:

```
search.php?q=test&x=15&y=13
```

to go to:

```
search/test/
```

But I don't know how to do this. The search form uses `GET` and uses an `input` image to submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query string will always be in the same order this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*?)&x=(\d*)&y=(\d*)
RewriteRule ^/search.php /search/%1?x=%2&y=%3 [R,L]
```

Comment: I guess the “test” represents a variable value.

Comment: @Gumbo. Thanks. Changed it to set the url using the q parameter as variable.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer, but I didn't because it leaves the query string in place.  The OP clearly shows his example as /search/test without the query string.  Do you know how to remove the query string?  When I try your example I get:  `/search/test?x=15&y=13`

Comment: @jmort - To remove the query string you just end the substitution string with a question mark. It would be /search/%1?